# In Google Custom Search API for searchType=image what is the expected value for the "rights" field?

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I'm using the [PHP sdk](http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to do image searches

```
$service = new Google_Service_Customsearch($client);
$optParams = array(
        'imgType' => 'photo',
        'imgColorType' => 'color',
        'imgSize' => 'large',
        'searchType' => 'image',
        'num' => '5',
        'safe' => 'medium',
        'rights' => '(cc_publicdomain|cc_attribute|cc_sharealike)',
        'filter' => '1',
        'cx' => <my cx>,
        );
$results = $service->cse->listCse($query, $optParams);
```

but i'm unclear that the "rights" field is doing anything.

It seems to generating a curl request that looks like this...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?       
q=<query here>
&imgType=photo
&imgColorType=color
&imgSize=large
&searchType=image
&num=6
&safe=medium
&rights=%28cc_publicdomain%7Ccc_attribute%7Ccc_sharealike%29
&filter=1
&cx=<my cx>
```

but i'm not clear that is working the way i expect. my query returns different images then when I use the web form.

Additionally the [docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) unhelpfully states..

```
rights  | string    | Filters based on licensing. Supported values include:
        |           | cc_publicdomain, cc_attribute, cc_sharealike, cc_noncommercial,
        |           | cc_nonderived, and combinations of these.
```

however i never get an error with this field, i can put any junk i want into it.

what is the proper format google expects here?  comma delimited? array? piped ?

Also, the options listed in the docs do not seem to match up precisely with the options in the web form, and some insights there would be nice too.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm also trying to use the image search but not quite sure what should the `CX` should be.

Comment: I tested and I see the difference in results between 'rights' => '(cc_publicdomain)', vs 'rights' => '(cc_publicdomain|cc_attribute)',

Answer (score 0):

You can see here for licencing of custom search

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#licensing

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being thick, but that doc is not clear at all. what language is the example snippet in?  is that part of some SDK?  some of the doc documents HTTP param, some XML, and some in this unidentified "code"  More help please.

Comment: after googling, it seems to have jumped into the Javascript SDK  The previous section of doc was HTTP parameters, but then all the examples switch to JS without preamble.  which is not very useful.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful, the OP (and myself) clearly want to know about using th HTTP API, but this only mentions how to use a javascript SDK.